# How to make an anchor tag disable or enable after click

Tags: css, reactjs

How to make disable and enable anchor tag on event (onClick() event) in react js

```
<a
onClick={this.handleClick}
data-toggle="collapse"
id="Id123"
className="disabledCursor"
>
My Link
</a>
```

Comment: Probably your code what you have tried so far would be helpful. In the same time I have a GitHub repository which shows how to use toggle elements on click event based on state, take a look at here: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Just one suggestion, instead of `<a>` tag I would have a `<div>` or `<button>`, because an anchor is already redirecting the user for the value of `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we don't implement `disabled` with tag `a`, instead we use `button`. For instance

```
  <button disabled={disabled}>
    <a onClick={this.handleClick} >
  <button>
```

upon `handleClick` you can change `disabled` state.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the help of state and style. By changing colour style of the link while state is false we can implement that.
this.state = {
tagEnable: true
}

```
this.handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({tagEnable: false}) 
}
this.state.tagEnable ? 
<a
onClick={this.handleClick}
data-toggle="collapse"
id="Id123"
className="disabledCursor"
>
My Link
</a>
:
<a style={{textColor: "gray"}}
onClick={}
data-toggle="collapse"
id="Id123"
className="disabledCursor"
>
My Link
</a>
```